# Why does Haskell's Monad implementation fail function result differ from error's result?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand monads and reading it's type class definition:

```
class Monad m where
    .
    .
    .
fail :: String -> m a
fail msg = error msg
```

Now, the definition of error is:

```
error :: [Char] -> a
```

Shouldn't the type system complain in this case? as
`a /= m a`

Or does the type system automatically assume that the results from error will be transformed into

```
m a
```

somehow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `a` is a different `a` than the one in `m a`. See it like `error :: [Char] -> b`, then `b ~ m a`.

Comment: That explains it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Put another way, the set of types that `fail` promises it can return is a strict subset of the set of types `error` promises it can return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `a`s in `fail`'s and `error`'s type signatures are a type variables. We can rename them without changing their meaning, e.g.

```
error :: [Char] -> b
error :: [Char] -> c
error :: [Char] -> d
```

All those type signatures have the same meaning; we just used alpha conversion on the type level.

Now we set `b ~ m a`, where `m` is fixed by `fail`'s context and we see that `error` can get used:

```
fail :: String -> m a
fail msg = error msg    -- error :: String -> b
                        --                    b ~ m a
```